# R - how to get to the underlying matrices while using regression in lm?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

Imagine you have data like this:

```
Y <- rnorm(100)
x <- rnorm(100)
z <- rnorm(100)

data <- data.frame(Y, x, z)
```

To this we can fit a linear model:

[image]

```
fit <- lm(Y ~ x + z, data)
```

The article states that the regression estimation is done by solving a system of normal equations:

[image]

Or in matrix form:

[image]

Having fit a `lm` object, how could I extract the `d` and `S` matrices?

Comment: Maybe you want to use `model.matrix(fit)` which returns the design matrices?

Comment: for the record, while this is certainly **a** correct way to compute regression coefficients, it's not the way it's done in R (look up "linear regression by QR decomposition")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can get `X` and `Y` from `fm` as shown.  Then use `crossprod` to compute `XtX` and `XtY` and then `solve` to get the coefficients.

```
fm <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + carb, mtcars)
 
X <- model.matrix(fm)

Y <- model.response(model.frame(fm))
# or
Y <- fitted(fm) + resid(fm)

XtX <- crossprod(X); XtX
##             (Intercept)  cyl carb
## (Intercept)          32  198   90
## cyl                 198 1324  604
## carb                 90  604  334

XtY <- crossprod(X,Y); XtY
##               [,1]
## (Intercept)  642.9
## cyl         3693.6
## carb        1641.9

c(solve(XtX, XtY))
## [1] 37.812739 -2.625023 -0.526146

coef(fm)
## (Intercept)         cyl        carb 
##   37.812739   -2.625023   -0.526146
```